# Get words from string - skip html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I use a function to get the first "x" words of a string. Main part is:

```
preg_match_all('/(<\/?([\w+]+)[^>]*>)?([^<>]*)/', $text, $tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

When a word is inside html - example:

```
<a href="/"><u>Linktext</u></a>
```

The regex see the word "linktext" as a word. Regex should be changed to **skip**  every word that is inside a html tag.

Is this possible?

Comment: So do you want all text **outside** of html tags?

Comment: @user2057781  Try this `(?<!\>)\b(<\/?([\w+]+)[^>]*>)?([^<>]*)\b(?!\<)`

Comment: @tchelidze this removes every html

Comment: Please provide some more input strings.

Comment: what do you mean with input strings?

Comment: You can skip something by using [verbs (*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs): `>[^<]+<(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+`. [Try on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xQ1fG6/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble thanks for you input. sorry I dont understand regex. Would you please add me your code into my regex? thank you

Comment: Please provide better/more input samples in your question and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @user2057781, If I understood you correctly, with the following exemplary input text: `'<a href="/"><u>Link text</u></a>some text<b>hidden</b>another text'` the final output should be: `'<a href="/"><u></u></a>some text<b></b>another text'`? Right ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest no thats no correct, I try it again:

I use a function to trim / truncate / cut a long string but keep html. The function (from cakephp) works great but when a word is inside a html tag, it  becomes also trimed. That means: some text <a href="/"><u>Link text</u></a> some text

becomes to 

some text <a href="/"><u>Link te...</u></a>

but I need it like this:

some text...

Words inside of html should be skiped while html should be presaved (the html save is working)

Comment: This question you refer to was removed, unfortunately. You should provide the complete explanation in the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Use XSL transformations. I used template from related answer ([How to remove all text from an XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427926/how-to-remove-all-text-from-an-xml-document)):

```
$string = '<a href="/">Some text <u>Linktext</u> more text</a>';
$xslTemplate = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <!-- copy all nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- clear attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" />
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- ignore text content of nodex -->
  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$inputDom = new DOMDocument();
$inputDom->loadHTML($string);

$xslDom = new DOMDocument();
$xslDom->loadXML($xslTemplate);

$cp = new XSLTProcessor();
$cp->registerPHPFunctions();
$cp->importStylesheet($xslDom);

$transformedResult = $cp->transformToDoc($inputDom);
$transformedHtmlString = $transformedResult->saveXML($transformedResult->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));

$transformedHtmlString = str_replace('<body>','', $transformedHtmlString); //saveXml() method leaves automatically created body tag
$transformedHtmlString = str_replace('</body>','', $transformedHtmlString);
echo $transformedHtmlString;
```

Comment: I dont want use strip_tags. I need the html in the string.

Comment: I see now, see corrected answer. Beware also of HEREDOC enclosed tag 'XML;' that should be part of code of course.

Comment: maybe this sounds dump to you but I have only php files to work with the text. when I add this xml code to my php file I have syntax errors

Comment: This is because of missed HEREDOC enclosing tag i mentioned in comment above. I've converted HEREDOC to plain string to avoid incorrect parser behavior.